# The term 'Get-AzADServicePrincipal' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to set access policy in azure key vault by following below msdn docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-powershell

I followed the steps like installed AzureAd in the powershell and connected with azure. But when I run the next steps I'm facing the issue like

```
Get-AzADServicePrincipal : The term 'Get-AzADServicePrincipal' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString PI
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzADServicePrincipal:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Not sure what are the steps I'm missing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should probably provide more information about the Azure module version and the PowerShell version you're using.

Answer (score 5):

Try running the install again with -AllowClobber.

Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber

Comment: This was possibly the correct response as of 2021 but from 2023/2024 onwards the Install-Module AzureAD command is correct. 
This is then followed by a Connect-AzureAD command to initiate connection to a tennant

Comment: @JohnYoungtree, could you provide your source for your answer?  According to this link, AzureAD is deprecated.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: The depreciation on that article has only just come around since my writing. It is planned for depreciation also, not depreciated yet.

Answer (score 0):

The command `Get-AzADServicePrincipal` is in the module `Az.Resources`. It does  not a command of `AzureAD` module. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-6.0.0).

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

1. Assign your account to [Azure AD role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference)
2. Script

```
Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzADServicePrincipal
```

[image]